# TextBox AutoCompleteStringCollection Suggest

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, autosuggest

I have created a form in C# with a CustomSource for a textbox:

```
public partial class FormLookup : Form
{

    AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();


    public FormLookup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        source.Add("Test");
        source.Add("TestItem");
        source.Add("TestValue");
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The purpose of what I am looking for is to select multiple values from the auto suggestion list. When the user selected the first value, a seperator like ';' should trigger the auto suggestion again.

It should look like this:

[image]

Maybe some code/idea in the _TextChanged method?
Is it possible in C# to highlight the selected value like in pic2?

Your ideas are welcome!

Comment: I think you need to implement your own textbox for that feature, or use some 3rd party control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom control for this requirement.
I have created similar one. posting logic and code - hope it may help you in getting basic Idea.

You need to create two user controls.

1. Custom Control (container for second user control + text box which you show us in question)
2. Tag control (will contain label to show Text of tag and link label 'x' to remove it)
   Together it will create a visualization of single unit custom control. where you can type (with you drop down suggestion) and once you press ',' , it will create a tag and store it within.

It will look like below,
[image]

Here is code for that.

Custom Control will have following cnntrols by default

```
private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flayoutCustomControlContainer;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1; //Marking this public so it can be directly accessed by external code.
```

here `flayoutCustomControlContainer` is containing `textBox1` by default.

`textBox1` will have Key Up event, which will be like below.

```
        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma) //we will perform this on every ',' press
            {
                flayoutCustomControlContainer.Controls.Remove(textBox1);

                TagControl tag = new TagControl(); //creating new Tag control
                tag.lblTagName.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());
                tag.Remvoed += tag_Remvoed; //subscribing "Removed" event of Tag

                tag.Width = tag.lblTagName.Width + 50;
                tag.Height = tag.lblTagName.Height + 5;

                flayoutCustomControlContainer.Controls.Add(tag);

                textBox1.Text = "";

                flayoutCustomControlContainer.Controls.Add(textBox1);

                textBox1.Focus();
            }
        }


void tag_Remvoed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.flayoutCustomControlContainer.Controls.Remove((Control)sender);
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Constructor of Custom Control, as you shown in question,

```
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        source.Add("Test");
        source.Add("TestItem");
        source.Add("TestValue");
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
    }
```

Now, Tag Control.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
    public  System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTagName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel llblRemove;
```

link label, llblRemove will have link lable click event which will raise an event, which Custom control is listing.

```
private void llblRemove_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
     if (Remvoed != null)
         Remvoed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Now, use this Custom Control anywhere you want to use.

I have uploaded working example project on GitHub.

Find a [**Link**](https://github.com/anutural/Trial)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I give response about my progress and will accept this answer.

Comment: Awesome idea/solution - Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasAlt I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need create your own component.
The structure can be be:

```
Panel (the main container with white background and border)
 |-> FlowLayoutPanel (the container for already added tags); Dock = Left
 |    |-> TagControl (you custom control for tag label)
 |    |-> ...        (more tags if required)
 |-> TextBox (the one with autocompletion with no borders); Dock = Fill;
```

You can encapsulate to your own Control/UserControl and use that event from Toolbox in designer.