# How to dynamically remove a UserControl from the form in c #?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a UserControl that is dynamically added to a FlowLayoutPanel. In that same UserControl I have a button to remove itself if the user wants it, obviously at runtime. To eliminate I mean not only to eliminate that tight button, but also the full UserControl that contains the button.
The code of when the UserControl are added dynamically at the moment is as follows:

```
    private void agregaUC() {
        UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1();
        aux += 1;
        UC.Tag = aux.ToString();
        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(UC);
    }
```

The code to eliminate this is on the side of the form, that is, where the UserControl are being added. The button event to remove the UserControl is thrown by code through the operator + =, then there I write the suggestions that you give me.

Comment: look my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154794/3901530) it is doing exactly same what you want.. there i have added git's link for working sample project too. (you can ignore auto complete textbox part of code there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Based on the sample of code you've added, I've modified the below code to work better with what you are looking for. You need to find out how to access the Tag of the control you're trying to remove.

Since you don't have a reference, then you should make sure that the `.Tag` property can be found, because then you can do something like

```
  foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel2.Controls) {
    if (c.Tag == "Aux") {
      flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Remove(c);
      c.Dispose();
      break;
    }
  }
```

## EDIT

Reading through all the comments everywhere, it seems like this is what's happening. There is a `UserControl`, inside that user control is a `Button` (Delete) and the button's `Click` event is subscribed to by the window, and it's in this event handler that we're trying to remove the `UserControl` from `flowLayoutPanel2`

Based on these assumptions, your function should look like this:

```
void UserControl_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button Delete = (Button)sender;
    UserControl UC = (UserControl)Delete.Parent;
    flowLayoutControl2.Controls.Remove(UC);
    UC.Dispose();
}
```

This is assuming a lot about the internal structure of everything, as I don't have the code to confirm this will work. It will get you a long ways down the path, though, and should only need a little tweaking based on the actual structure of the `UserControl`.

Comment: The problem of that, as I know which UserControl is being removed. In other words, I do not know what to put between the quotes "", because inisisto, I do not know how to access the tag of that UserControl in question.

Comment: @yerald, I've updated the comment to better match the code you gave in your question. I don't know the structure of the UserControl, so I can't tell you how to get the tag to use within this code, but this is the best way to remove it once you find a way to identify it.

Comment: Friend, I thank you for your patience and your support in the thread of the question. The SECOND CODE served me, best of all, you gave me an efficient answer. I learned something more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Control.Parent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Remark: Setting the Parent property value to null removes the control from the Control.ControlCollection of its current parent control.

So

```
this.Parent = null;
```

**Edit**

The code is intended to be called from within the user control itself.

Comment: I get absolutely nothing with your code. Not an error either.

Comment: So what is the value of `this.Parent` *before* setting it to null? add a breakpoint there to examine. If this user control is added to a FlowLayoutPanel, `this.Parent` should be the FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Where is this line of code being called? from the button's Click event handler, right?

Comment: If, indeed, the line of code is called from the click event, at the zero time of execution the UserControl are not, after some maneuvers these are added to the FlowLayoutPanel dynamically. Inside these UserControl there is a "Delete" button, whose role is to eliminate the UserControl that obviously contains that button. I think that would be clearer there.

Comment: Could you show the code that the user control is added to the panel dynamically?

Comment: I put the code at the beginning.... 


I saw that you told Cory Dohm that the code was written on the side of the UserControl, that is not so, because I have it on the side of the form, that is, where the UserControl are being added. The button event to remove the UserControl is thrown by code through the operator + =, then there I write the suggestions that you give me.

Comment: Then Cory’s answer is correct. You can give it a name or just use the Tag to find the user control, then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that.

`this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);`

Comment: By putting your line of code I get the following error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set as an instance of an object.'

Comment: `this.Parent?.Controls?.Remove(this);`